# properties in .animate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate

I am trying to have my background color change when somebody his a button however it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm storing hex colors in an array then usinf math.random to generate a random color. I've been debugging in chrome and can't figure out the issue.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var colors = ['#E9967A', '#FF8C00', '#4682B4', '#CD853F', '#008080', '#27ae60', '#2c3e50', '#f39c12', '#e74c3c', '#9b59b6', '#fb9664', '#bdbb99', '#77b1a9', '#73a857'];


    $("#getQuote").on("click", function(){
      $.getJSON("http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/method=getQuote&format=json&lang=en", function(json) {
        $(".id").html(JSON.stringify(json));
      });
    });

    $("getQuote").click(function(){
      var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
      $("html body").animate({
        backgroundColor: colors[color]
      }, 1000);
    });
  });
```

edit I posted all of the code to give a better idea of what's going on

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You need to reassign color to call random, thus generating a new number or else `color` stays the same after generated.

Comment: Without using jQuery **UI** - the background property will not animate - unless you use CSS3 and `body{transition: 0.5s;}`. Also your random needs to be inside the click event if you want to generate always a new color.

Comment: Modifying your question according to suggestions is not helpful to track your issue and the provided answers might seem funny at least.

Comment: `$("getQuote")` do you see anything missing here? (I do.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four issues with `javascript` at Question.

- Selector `"getQuote"` is not an `html` element; missing `"#"` at beginning of selector string.
- jQuery [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) does not animate colors by default

  > Animation Properties and Values
  >
  > All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value,
  >   except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be
  >   animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height,
  >   or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the
  >   [`jQuery.Color`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color) plugin is used).
- Missing opening `{` at first parameter passed to `.animate()`; e.g., `.animate({property:value})`
- `color` variable will not change at each `click` event at `#getQuote` element, as `color` is defined outside of `.click()` handler

You can use jQuery UI to animate colors

```js
$(function() {

var colors = ['#E9967A', '#FF8C00', '#4682B4', '#CD853F'
              , '#008080', '#27ae60', '#2c3e50', '#f39c12'
              , '#e74c3c', '#9b59b6', '#fb9664', '#bdbb99'
              , '#77b1a9', '#73a857'];

  $("#getQuote").click(function() {
    var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    $("html body").animate({
      backgroundColor: colors[color]
    }, 1000);
  });

})
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <button id="getQuote">click</button>
</body>
```

You can alternatively utilize `css` `transition` at `body` selector, `.css()`

```js
$(function() {

var colors = ['#E9967A', '#FF8C00', '#4682B4', '#CD853F'
              , '#008080', '#27ae60', '#2c3e50', '#f39c12'
              , '#e74c3c', '#9b59b6', '#fb9664', '#bdbb99'
              , '#77b1a9', '#73a857'];


  $("#getQuote").click(function() {
    var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    $("html body").css("backgroundColor", colors[color]);
  });

})
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<body>
  <button id="getQuote">click</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

the firs thing struck is to place this string:

    `var color = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);`

within the event, so the color will be generated when click happens, otherwise it will be always the same color (I did not try it so maybe i'm wrong)

Answer (score 1):

You could make your color variable into a function that returns a calculated value each time

```
var color = fn => Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
```

and then call it as a function when you reference the color index

```
backgroundColor: colors[color()]
```